# GoDaddy can't find Exception.php file

Tags: phpmailer

I'm trying to send email on a GoDaddy website.  When I test the code on my PC it works.  When I move it to GoDaddy I get the following error:

[27-Jan-2024 03:12:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(/home/rgbcfe/public_html\PHPMailer\Exception.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/rgbcfe/public_html/phpmailerTest.php on line 6

[27-Jan-2024 03:12:06 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/rgbcfe/public_html\PHPMailer\Exception.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php81/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php81/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/rgbcfe/public_html/phpmailerTest.php:6

To try to fix this I created new directories off of where the code is running: /usr/share/php and moved Exception.php into the php folder.  That didn't fix the error.  I'm not sure what to do.

Thanks for any help.